How automatically start Thunderbird minimized on AlmaLinux (Wayland)?
I am looking for a way to automatically start Thunderbird 115.13.0 minimized on AlmaLinux 9.4. AlmaLinux uses Wayland, and Thunderbird was installed using dnf install thunderbird. I don't care if it is minimized in the dock or in the top bar, the main thing is that it starts and is minimized.
Since Thunderbird does not have such an option (why?), apparently we have to “simulate” a mouse click to minimize it.
The proposed solution so far―birdtray―didn't work in this distro: Installed as flatpak, it couldn't find the Thunderbird window and also couldn't find the binary, even though /usr/bin/ is on the PATH. This is probably due to Birdtray's isolation in the flatpak environment, but not sure.
Error starting Thunderbird as '/usr/bin/thunderbird ':   
execvp: No such file or directory

$ which thunderbird
/usr/bin/thunderbird

Compiling Birdtray from source unfortunately segfaulted.
Also the script below, using wmctrl, wasn't successful.
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
                                                                                
# Start Thunderbird                                                             
thunderbird &                                                                   
                                                                                
# Give Thunderbird some time to start                                           
sleep 5                                                                         
                                                                                
# Get all Thunderbird window IDs                                                
window_ids=$(xdotool search --class Thunderbird)                                
                                                                                
# Iterate over each window ID and minimize the viewable main window             
for id in $window_ids; do                                                       
    map_state=$(xwininfo -id $id | grep "Map State")                            
    window_name=$(xprop -id $id | grep "WM_NAME")                               
    if [[ $map_state == *"IsViewable"* && $window_name == *"Mozilla Thunderbird"* ]]; then
        xdotool windowminimize $id                                              
        echo "Minimized window ID: $id"                                         
        break                                                                   
    fi                                                                          
done     

$ ./start_thunderbird_minimized.sh 
Window not found, retrying...
Window not found, retrying...
Window not found, retrying...

Weirdly enough, when trying xprop to verify the correct window ID, it can't find the Thunderbird window either. When clicking on Thunderbird window literally nothing happens, whci might be due to Wayland?

xprop doesn't work under Wayland. Also enjoy https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland/-/issues/233

@ArtemS.Tashkinov Great they draw conclusions for us, so we don't have to bother. Switching to X11 has relieved the pain. The script, in combination with a corresponding .desktop for the autostart, worked immediately like a charm. You might post your comment as a quick answer.

you actually penned an answer, I just gave you a valuable hint :-) Please post it yourself.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov Very well. I did it.

Apperently a Wayland issue (credits to @ArtemS.Tashkinov). Switching to X11 has relieved the pain. The script (see OP), in combination with a corresponding .desktop file for the autostart, worked immediately like a charm. Assuming the script lives in $HOME/Scripts/thunderbird_startup.sh, the .desktop file looks like this:
$ cat ~/.config/autostart/thunderbird_startup.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=$HOME/Scripts/thunderbird_startup.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Thunderbird Startup
Comment=Start Thunderbird and minimize the window

